# How to integrate Paypal into ASP.Net c# server side code

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal-sandbox

How to integrate PAYPAL Sandbox Account in my ASP.net webpages? 
Please give me complete example of source code or URL.

I don't have Any experience to develop any payment system . So please help me.

Comment: http://www.codersbarn.com/?tag=/paypal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the link below to integrate Sandbox Paypal Integration

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/